# Sequences Eventually and Frequently in a Set

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, logic, predicate-logic

A sequence $(a_n)$ is eventually in an set $A \subseteq \mathbb R$ if there exists an $N \in \mathbb N$ such that $a_n \in A$ for all $n \ge N.$

A sequence $(a_n)$ is frequently in an set $A \subseteq \mathbb R$ if, for every $N \in \mathbb N$ there exists an $n \ge N$ such that $a_n \in A$.

Question: Which definition is stronger? Does frequently imply eventually or eventually imply frequently?

Intuitively I am inclined to say that eventually implies frequently because from examples I reason that the sequence ${\lfloor \frac{5}{n}\rfloor}$ is eventually in $\{0\}$ and also frequently in $\{0\}$ but a sequence like $(-1)^n$ which is frequently in $\{1\}$ but not eventually.

However from looking at the quantifiers it seems to me that the converse should be true for I reason

$$\forall N \exists n(n \ge N \Rightarrow a_n \in A)$$ should imply 
$$\exists N \exists n(n \ge N \Rightarrow a_n \in A)$$ (i.e. frequnctly implies eventually)?

> Am I making a mistake with the quantifiers? Which one is correct? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Eventually is $\exists N \mathbf{\ast}{\forall}\mathbf{\ast} ~ n (n \ge N \Rightarrow a_n \in A)$.

Comment: @Daniel, I think you meant to say that is "eventually" which IS stronger than "frequently" since in "eventually", there is a single $N$ after which the whole sequence lies in $A$ vs. frequently which just says that arbitrarily large indices lie in $A$.

Comment: Your expression for eventually is wrong. The second quantifier must be $\forall$.

Answer (score 2):

Expression for eventually:$$\exists N\forall n\geq N[a_n\in A]$$

Equivalent is the statement: $$\liminf1_A(a_n)=1$$

Expression for frequently:$$\forall N\exists n\geq N[a_n\in A]$$

Equivalent is the statement: $$\limsup1_A(a_n)=1$$

We always have: $$\liminf1_A(a_n)\leq\limsup1_A(a_n)\leq1$$so eventually implies frequently.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually implies frequently.  If $a_n \in A$ for all $n \ge N$, then for every $n$ you can take $m = \max(n,N)$ and have $m \ge n$ and $a_m \in A$.

Comment: Yes but then what is my mistake with the quantifiers?